# how to use cv2.cvtColor function

Tags: python, opencv

see code
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import faceRecognition as fr

```
test_img=cv2.imread('H:\faceRecognition\TestImages\img.jpg')
    faces_detected,gray_img = fr.faceDetection(test_img)
    print("faces_detected:",faces_detected)

for(x,y,w,h) in faces_detected: 
    cv2.rectangle(test_img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),thickness=5)

resized_img=cv2.resized_img(test_img,(1000,700))
cv2.imshow("Face Detection Tutorial",resized_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import cv2

defimg = 'H:\\faceRecognition\\TestImages\\img.jpg'
outimg = 'H:\\faceRecognition\\TestImages\\output_img.jpg'

common_available_spaces = {
    '8': cv2.CV_8U,       # 8-bit unsigned (0-255)
    '16': cv2.CV_16U,     # 16-bit unsigned (0-65535)
    '32': cv2.CV_32F      # 1 precision floating point (0-1)
}
OUTPUT_COLOR_SPACE = common_available_spaces['8']

cv2.cvtColor(src=defimg, code=OUTPUT_COLOR_SPACE, dst=outimg)
```